# Ruby case statements with multiple variables

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching, case

Ruby has a fairly powerful `case..when..else` construct for when you need to match criteria against a single variable. What is the "canonical" way to match criteria against multiple variables without simply nesting `case` statements?

Wrapping multiple variables in an array (like `[x, y]`) and matching against it isn't equivalent, because Ruby won't apply the magical `case ===` operator to the *elements* of the array; the operator is only applied to the array itself.

I'm going to go ahead and respond with a community-wiki answer with a (defeated) stab at this question.

Comment: As far as I know, Ruby does apply `===` to each element recursively... http://ideone.com/yMAlZ

Comment: @Nakilon I've tested, and it doesn't appear to apply it recursively. For example, `['hello', 3]` won't match with `[String, 3]`.

Comment: aaaa... sorry, my fault. Forgot difference between `==` and `===`.

Comment: I suspect that Array inherits `===` from Object, so the default behavior is to compare the hash values of both sides of the test, not to test the contents. If you want a test of types and values, you'll need to add `===` to Array and implement the behavior desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simplistic way to add `===`:

```
class Array
  def ===(other)
    return false if (other.size != self.size)

    other_dup = other.dup
    all? do |e|
      e === other_dup.shift
    end
  end
end

[
  ['foo', 3],
  %w[ foo bar ],
  %w[ one ],
  []
].each do |ary|

  ary_type = case ary
  when [String, Fixnum] then "[String, Fixnum]"
  when [String, String] then "[String, String]"
  when [String] then "[String]"
  else
    "no match"
  end

  puts ary_type

end

# >> [String, Fixnum]
# >> [String, String]
# >> [String]
# >> no match
```

Comment: +1 This is definitely cleaner than my second answer, but isn't modifying the built-in classes somewhat discouraged? That's a genuine question; I'm new to Ruby.

Comment: Also, why are you making a copy of `other`? Will `shift` affect the array passed as the parameter otherwise? I suppose I'll update my example to reflect that (I already stole `Array.all?`, which I didn't know about...

Comment: I think it's safe modifying Array this way, since Array doesn't implement `===`. You get into potentially unsafe waters when you override a base class in a way that breaks expected behavior.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted my second answer. For those who were curious, it was a `Match` class that implemented operator `===`. An array could be passed to its constructor with `Match.new([String, 1..10])`, so it could be used after `when`.

Comment: Do not monkey patch core classes for "convenience" like this, it is a bad practice. At best, it is confusing to people reading your code. At worst, `===` may be added in the future, or someone else is overriding it expecting a different behaviour. If you really want to do this, wrap your arrays in a custom class that implements `===` (such as the `BiPartite` class below).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an `if..elsif..else`, and ensure that the variables you want to match against appear on the right-hand side of the `===` operator (which is what `case` essentially does).

For example, if you want to match `x` and `y` against some criteria:

```
if (SomeType === x) && (1..10 === y)
  some_value
elsif (:some_symbol === x) && (11..20 === y)
  some_other_value
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If this pattern is common enough in your code to warrant economical expression, you can do it yourself:

```
class BiPartite
  attr_reader :x, :y

  def self.[](x, y)
    BiPartite.new(x, y)
  end

  def initialize(x, y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end

  def ===(other)
    x === other.x && y === other.y
  end
end

....

case BiPartite[x, y]
when BiPartite[SomeType, 1..10]
  puts "some_value"
when BiPartite[:some_symbol, 11..20]
  puts "some_other_value"
end
```

Comment: +1 Is there a non-disgusting way to make this work with an arbitrary number of parameters? Actually, ideas are popping into my mind, and they don't involve altering the `Array` class...

Answer (score 1):

Since Ruby's `when` keyword supports a comma separated list of values, you could use the splat `*` operator.  This is, of course, assuming that you're referring to a set of discrete values that are in or could become an array.

The splat operator converts a list of arguments into an array, as frequently seen in

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
```

Less well known is the fact that it also performs the inverse operation - turning an array into a list of arguments.

So in this case, you could do something like

```
passing_grades = ['b','c']
case grade
when 'a'
  puts 'great job!'
when *passing_grades
  puts 'you passed'
else
  puts 'you failed'
end
```

Comment: After re-reading this, I may mave mis-read the original question - I thought the comparison was between one variable and an array of possible matching values for it.

Answer (score 0):

My not battled tested solution is to call `.map(&:class)` and then is the array in the `when` statements

```rb
def foo(a, b)
  case [a,b].map(&:class)
  when [Integer, Integer]
    puts "Integer"
  when [String, String]
    puts "String"
  else 
    puts "otherwise"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with strings, or something that converts to strings easily, you might like this solution:

```
case [city, country].join(", ")
when "San Jose, Costa Rica"
  # ...
when "San Jose, USA"
  # ...
when "Boston, USA"
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```